# How to display timestamp on QT correctly?

Tags: qt, qt4, timestamp

I try to get current time (timestamp) on qt.

```
myvar1=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
qDebug()<<myvar1;
```

In Aplication Output i see strage symbols like | â É etc. I expect 1407112707.
So my timestamp is not correct.
How to display timestamp on QT correctly?

Comment: What is the type of `myvar1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason is that you've declared `myvar1` incorrecly. Declare it as `quint64`.

```
quint64 myvar1 = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
qDebug() << myvar1;
```

Also you can use `QString::number(myvar1);` to get a string representation.